# How to update a value in a nested dictionary in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this nested dictionary:

```
userdict = {'userone': {'valueone': 1, 'valuetwo': 1}}
userdict['usertwo']={'valueone': 1, 'valuetwo': 1}
```

I process this with:

```
for i in userdict.keys():
    print(i)
    for j in userdict[i].keys():
        print(j)
    
        userdict[i]={'valuetwo': 0}
```

After this process i get:

```
{'userone': {'valuetwo': 0}, 'usertwo': {'valuetwo': 0}}
```

but i want:

```
{'userone': {'valueone': 1, 'valuetwo': 0}, 'usertwo': {'valueone': 1, 'valuetwo': 0}}
```

How can i stop overwriting "valueone"?

Comment: Great question. It's well-posed because it has the minimal code to reproduce the issue, it has the output you get, and the expectation. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the entire dictionary at `userdict[i]`, but instead you want to overwrite the *entry* for `userdict[i]['valuetwo']`, so

```
userdict[i]['valuetwo'] = 0
```